# Issue about posting form data by using axios

Tags: reactjs, redux, axios

I'm working on registration. everything was good before adding the profile image.

this is the registration page onSubmit method

```
const handleSubmit = (event) => {
            event.preventDefault();
            const user_data = {
                userID: userID,
                password: password,
                firstName: firstName,
                lastName: lastName,
                email: email
            }
            dispatch(register(user_data, profileImageFile))
    };
```

and this is the actual axios

```
const register = async (user_data, imgFile) => {
    console.log(user_data, imgFile)
    formData.append('userID', user_data.userID);
    formData.append('password', user_data.password);
    formData.append('firstName', user_data.firstName);
    formData.append('lastName', user_data.lastName);
    formData.append('email', user_data.email);
    formData.append('imgFile', imgFile);
    for (var pair of formData.entries()) { console.log(pair[0] + ', ' + pair[1]); }
    return await axios.post("/registration", formData
        , {
            headers: { 'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data' }
        }
    )

}
```

I verified formdata had all the text data and image well. but at the backend, any data wasn't appear.
When I put in another data without an image file, it worked well.
what is the problem with that?

Comment: You need something like multer in the back

Comment: oh Jesus, I owe you. Thanks a lot